# Running two servers in java Blade Framework

Tags: java, web, server

I am using [Java Blade Framework](https://github.com/lets-blade/blade).

I'm trying to do that each server listens on its own port. However, when running two (or more) servers, only the first one works.

When I try to open the ***http://localhost:8082/world*** in browser (server 2), it looks for the necessary route in the first server (I found this out using logging). And I get 404 error. If I swap the start of the servers, then all paths will be searched in the first one.

This is my code:

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Blade.create()
            .get("/hello", ctx -> ctx.text("hello!"))
            .listen(8081)
            .start()
            .await();

        Blade.create()
            .get("/world", ctx -> ctx.text("world!"))
            .listen(8082)
            .start()
            .await();

        // http://localhost:8081/hello -> 202 ok
        // http://localhost:8082/world -> 404 not found -> 
        // -> searches path "/world" in the first server
    }
}
```

**How can I start two servers?**

Comment: misunderstood, yeah...hope someone can help (tried to boost this with the +1(+

Comment: The Blade has a Netty server under the hood and can listen only to a single port. So, there is always a single server with possible multiple routes. If you really want to start two different servers you should separate your code into two different modules, create separate jar files and run them independently on different ports. Or, just think if separate routes will be enough to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Ilya Lapitan for giving [complete answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73967234/running-two-servers-in-java-blade-framework?noredirect=1#comment130627878_73967234) to the question in the comments.

I will also add that I was able to run 2 servers in the application using the [Javalin library](https://javalin.io/). The code style is very similar to Blade.

```
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Javalin.create()
            .get("/hello", ctx -> ctx.result("hello!"))
            .start(8080);

        Javalin.create()
            .get("/world", ctx -> ctx.result("world!"))
            .start(8081);
    }
}
```